# Java Build Path

Tags: java, jar, buildpath

I have a quick question about altering the build path as the code is running.

For example, I have a class which downloads a .jar file from the internet and then into the same directory as the code is running from.  How, if possible, could I load the jar into the build path to access the classes within the .jar file?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggested amendments / comments:

- Remove the `jar:` prefix and the `!/` suffix - these are note required and are probably confusing the matter
- Can you verify the jar file exists:

  `System.out.println(new File(new URL("file://test.jar")).exists());`
- Amend your class declaration to the following (get the File object to generate the URL for you, to avoid problems):

  `URL[] classes = new URL[] { new File("test.jar").toURI().toURL() };`

This worked for my test example, using commons-codec as the jar, and loading the Base64 class