# Java: Get a class from an external .jar

Tags: java, class, url, import, buildpath

I have a problem with getting a class from an external .jar file.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) method of loading an external .jar here but whenever I run it, I get a ClassNotFoundException.  Below is the code I am using and [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47241564/Test.jar) is the .jar I am testing with.  If anyone has any idea about how to fix this please do tell me.  Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked", "unused" })
public void loadJar() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL[] classes = {new URL("jar:file://test.jar!/")};
    URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (classes, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    try {
        Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("test.PackageTest", true, child);
        Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("test");
        Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
        Object result = method.invoke(instance);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's up with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880385/java-build-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking `URL[] classes = {new URL("jar:file://test.jar!/")};` into a few statements

```
File myFile = new File("test.jar");
URL myJarFileURL = new URL("jar", "", "file:" + myFile.getAbsolutePath() + "!/");
URL[] classes = {myJarFileURL};
```

You can send myFile.getAbsolutePath() to a logger or the console and see where the class loader is expecting to find test.jar. Then make sure that test.jar is in that location.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the jar: and !/ in the URL.