# Plugin executable jar file at execution time

Tags: java, runtime, executable-jar, software-design

Here is the thing, I want to build a system that shall take an external executable jar( later any .exe as such/ can be extended to API, but that's very long term) to a local Java executable(let's call it the Engine) at execution time. I'm thinking like to pass the name of the jar(let's call it the plugin) to the Engine, there would be a standard method for communication when conformed, both the Engine and Plugin would communicate. How can I do that without building a lot from scratch. I'm thinking in a very bookish way, can I use/study any existing method/framework. My whole system is built in Java so I am bound by the language mostly.

Comment: How `import external.executable.jar`  do not solve your problem?

Comment: I want to do it in execution time, like an argument.

Comment: Use URLClassLoader and Class.forName

Comment: Ok. I'll check that. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Get a class from an external .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881393/java-get-a-class-from-an-external-jar)

Comment: Might not. Because to be exact this is what it looks like in a very rough way, At execution, I want to pass like java -jar Engine.jar Plugin.jar and then these two shall communicate.

Comment: What you are referring to is probably reflection which I'm not yet sure if this would solve my issue or not. For that, I came here to get some leads.

Comment: Give it a test, read the documentation of these classes/methods. It is expected on your side to try and research what it is suggested before hasting conclusions.

Comment: Sure, I'll check.

Comment: You are trying to reach several different things with your question: One is how to load a class from an external jar (I have already provided to you a few tips to solve that one), the other is how to *add an external jar into the execution of a java program*, I'd suggest you open up a different question for that one once you know how to solve the first part of the problem.

Comment: Yup, let me see in detail. There are few things I might put up as constraints too in the application, like a signature for the Plugin file. I'll do some more research and update this post. Thanks for the cue.